# FastAPI endpoints testing with aiohttp

Tags: pytest, fastapi, aiohttp

I want to test my application on fastAPI. I use pytest and it came to endpoint test, I decided to use aiohttp. When I try to pass a pydantic schema to a request or json, everything breaks. My application is completely built on pydantic models, and I didn’t find anything with pydantic in the aiohttp documentation. And it turns out that the request only accepts a pydantic scheme, and aiohttp does not allow it to be transmitted. So i looking for help who familiar with testing

One of test case:

```
from src.backend.users.schemas import UsersScheme 
from tests.test_db import test_database_preparation 
import aiohttp

class TestUserAuthentication:
    async def test_user_registration(self, test_database_preparation):
    
        fake_user = {
            "username": "test",
            "non_hashed_password": "test"
        }
        user: UsersScheme = UsersScheme(**fake_user)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client_session:
            resp = await client_session.post(url="http://localhost:8000/users/register", json=user)
            #  resp = await client_session.post(url="http://localhost:8000/users/register", data=user)
            assert resp.status == 200
```

fixture (test_db_preparation):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function') 
async def test_database_preparation(): 
    assert settings.MODE == "TEST"

    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        connection: AsyncConnection
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    
        yield
    
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
```

UsersScheme:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UsersScheme(BaseModel):
    username: str
    non_hashed_password: str
```

When i put scheme object

`FAILED tests/integration_tests/test_auth_users.py::TestUserAuthentication::test_user_registration - TypeError: Object of type UsersScheme is not JSON serializable`

Or if i put not pydantic model, or json it gives 422 pydantic validation error:

`E           AssertionError: assert 422 == 200`

``` E            +  where 422 = <ClientResponse(``http://localhost:8000/users/register``) [422 Unprocessable Entity]>\n<CIMultiDictProxy('Date': 'Mon, 31 Jul 2023', 'Server': 'uvicorn', 'Content-Length': '248', 'Content-Type': 'application/json')>\n.status ```

`tests/integration_tests/test_auth_users.py:19: AssertionError`

simplified endpoint:

```
@router.post("/register")
async def new_user_registration(user: UsersScheme) -> str:
    #  ...
    return "OK"
```

So does this possible test api based on pydantic with aiohttp?Or its my fail? Any help or hint will help me!

P.S: I know about fastapi TestClient... it's not enough

Comment: Why do you say FastAPI's (technically starlette's) `TestClient` is not enough? It's literally an [`httpx.Client`](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#client-instances)

Comment: Regardless, the issue is most likely that you are passing a Pydantic model to `client_session.post`, you should set `json=user.model_dump()` (or `user.dict()` if you’re still using Pydantic 1.x.y).

Comment: Thank you! The main problems is in that I used model_dump() before and got the same 422 error even though it was a sqlalchemy error. The table was not created when control was passed to the ClientSession. 

engine.begin() is a transaction so when i do yield, transaction havent done yyet.